# How to add decimal numbers in xslt 1.0 in substrings

Tags: xml, numbers, substring, xslt-1.0

I have the following input xml.

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "UTF-8"?>
<values>
    <value>sometext;+123.23;+100.23</value>
    <value>sometext;+004.23;+444.12</value>
</values>
```

I am a newbie in XSL 1.0. I would like to add two decimal numbers received in strings but I am receiving NaN error. How do I do that. 
I would like to get the following output from the above input xml where the decimal values are summed but instead I am receiving NaN errors.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Results>
    <Result>+223.46</Result>
    <Result>+448.35</Result>
</Results>
```

I have the XSL file as follows,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match = "/"> 
<Results>
<xsl:for-each select="values/value">
  <Result>
     <xsl:value-of select="number(substring(.,10,7)) + 
   number(substring(.,18,7))" />
  </Result>
</xsl:for-each>
</Results>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A number is not allowed to contain a `+` sign.

Try instead:

```
<xsl:value-of select="substring(., 11, 6) + substring(., 19, 6)" />
```

(assuming of course that the positions and lengths are constant - and that the numbers are always positive).

---

My own preference would be to do:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/values"> 
    <Results>
        <xsl:for-each select="value">
            <xsl:variable name="a" select="substring-before(substring-after(., ';'), ';')" />
            <xsl:variable name="b" select="substring-after(substring-after(., ';'), ';')" />
            <Result>
                <xsl:value-of select="translate($a, '+', '') + translate($b, '+', '')" />
            </Result>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </Results>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

which will work with positive and negative numbers alike, and does not depend on the length of any one of the three tokens in the given string.

Comment: Incidentally, number() does accept a leading "+" sign from XSLT 2.0 onwards.